# Maclaurin of $f(x)=\ln\left(\sum_{k=0}^{1000}\frac{x^k}{k!}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, taylor-expansion

The 1001st order is required.

Here is how I went about the question:

We know that near $x=0$:

$$e^x=\sum_{k=0}^{1000}\frac{x^k}{k!}+\frac{x^{1001}}{1001!}+o(x^{1001})$$
So,
$$e^x-\frac{x^{1001}}{1001!}+o(x^{1001})=\sum_{k=0}^{1000}\frac{x^k}{k!}$$
And after taking the logarithm of both sides,
$$f(x)=\ln\left(e^x-\frac{x^{1001}}{1001!}+o(x^{1001})\right)$$

But what do I do next? I intuitively understand that the answer should be:
$$f(x)=x-\frac{x^{1001}}{1001!}+o(x^{1001})$$
But how do I prove it rigorously?

Thank you!

Comment: Factor out $e^x$ in the argument of $\ln$, then apply the fact that the look of a product is the sum of the logs. After this you can apply the Taylor series for the logarithm.

Comment: @sasquires

Do you mean: f(x)=x-ln(x^1001/1001!  *  1/e^x  + o(x^1001))

Then I use first term expansion of ln and e^x:

f(x)=x-x^1001/1001!  *  1/1  + o(x^1001) = x-x^1001/1001! + o(x^1001)

If that works, you are a genius, man!

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Two comments: 1. Writing $\frac{1}{e^x}$ as $e^{-x}$ makes it much easier to do the Taylor expansion properly.  2. If you want the $O(x^{1002})$ term, you have to be careful about handling the second-order parts of both the expansion of the logarithm and the exponential.  But for the $x^{1001}$ term, you are already done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-posting my comment as an answer since it resolved the question:

> Factor out $e^x$ in the argument of $\ln$, then apply the fact that the log of a product is the sum of the logs. After this you can apply the Taylor series for the logarithm.

Comment: Yes, sorry, haha!  Writing from my phone, which is why this answer is so short, and autocorrect kicked in.